# Create a new table from a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in mySQL with a parameter, How can i create a new table within the Stored procedure of pass the table name as Parameter to the Stored procedure.

Comment: I have tried Variable @tbl_name; SET tbl_name = 'tbl_output_tbl'+id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to create table and some other objects from the procedure -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1(IN tableName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', tableName, '(column1 INT(11))');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

More information about supported DML statements here - [SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Answer (score 1):

use this way to create a table dynamically.

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @fieldType VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @fieldName VARCHAR(50)
SET @tableName='abc'
SET @fieldType ='int'
SET @fieldName='id'


EXEC('CREATE TABLE '+@tableName+'( '+@fieldName+' '+@fieldType+' )')
```

hopefully my answer will help you. thankyou